# Having difficulties adding a player to a Team

Tags: java, bukkit

I am creating a game engine for my Bukkit server in Java using Bukkit API. I am having a problem with the following method in adding a player to that team.

```
public void add(Player player) {
  // If the player is trying to join his existing team.
  if (players.containsKey(player)) {
    player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "You cannot join your existing team."));
    return;
  }
  // If the team slots are maximized.
  if (players.size() > size) {
    player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "That team is full at the moment."));
    return;
  }
  for (Team team: getTeams()) {
    if (team.getPlayers()
      .containsKey(player)) {
      team.remove(player);
      // break; - Removed, still not solved.
    }
  }
  players.put(player, this);
  // Checking if the player joined the team.
  if (players.containsKey(player)) {
    Main.log("Joined " + player.getName() + " to the " + this.name + ".", Level.INFO);
    player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "You have joined the " + getColor() + ChatColor.BOLD + getName() + "."));
  }
}
```

**Is there a problem with that specific method?**

If yes, the problem with that code is, it will join the player to that Team, but if the Player is already in another team, it will **not** remove him from the ArrayList of the other Team, as a result, the player will be in multiple teams, which in that case I want to prevent that.

Any ideas on where the problem might lie?

---

**Update:**
After debugging with messages, I realized that the if-statement inside the `for-loop` returns false. That means the HashMap which stores the player keys does not contain the player. *Really odd*.

Comment: Well first of all, you are breaking out of the enhanced for loop for checking if the player exists in other teams. Remove the break; statement.

Comment: Try removing the `break;` in the `for (Team team : getTeams())` loop.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I just removed it, but the problem seems to still exist. Updating the question right now.

Comment: Interesting, I added a debug message "Triggered" in the for-loop, and it was not executed. That either means the loop did not worked, or the if-statement returned false.

Comment: Put a break point and debug it. It's hard to answer this without knowing where or how Teams get initialized or your "players" collection.

Comment: I thought of that as well, bad thing though I am working with a server console, I can only see stack-traces.

Comment: You add the player to the players list, but do you also add it to the actual player list of the desired team?

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved. @CAGGonzo, I was adding the player to the Team, but I was checking all registered teams, and not the match teams. But, thank you because you got me thinking.

Comment: No problem. You should post an answer with your updated code that fully solves your issue when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

## **Solved**

**I was looping all the teams instead of checking on the match one's.**

---

Working code:

```
public void add(Game game, Player player)
{
    // If the player is trying to join his existing team.

    if (players.containsKey(player))
    {
        player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "You cannot join your existing team."));
        return;
    }

    // If the team slots are maximized.

    if (players.size() > size)
    {
        player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "That team is full at the moment."));
        return;
    }

    for (Team team : game.getTeams())
    {
        if (team.getPlayers().get(player) != this)
        {
            team.remove(game, player);
        }
    }

    players.put(player, this);

    // Checking if the player joined the team.

    if (players.containsKey(player))
    {
        Main.log("Joined " + player.getName()  + " to the " + this.name + ".", Level.INFO);

        player.sendMessage(Chat.Info(getModuleName(), "You have joined the " + getColor() + ChatColor.BOLD + getName() + "."));
    }
}
```